# Repository of .qtz s in system files?

Tags: macos

Apparently there is a place within the OS's system files that have lots of .qtz s that you can use for your desktop background.

Could someone tell me the location of the files?

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and run `locate qtz` to get the list for your system. You may need to install Xcode to get the full set, with the added benefit of being able to run "/Developer/Applications/Quartz Composer.app" to develop your own.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for:

```
/System/Library/Graphics/Quartz Composer Patches/
```

..which are the examples that show in Quartz Composer's Library at launch, on 10.6.8 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `./System/Library/Compositions`, which is where the Quartz files are located for iTunes and Photo Booth (and a couple other system things I believe).

As for setting it as your desktop, I'm not sure about that. Simply dragging one to the image well in the Desktop & Screen Saver pane doesn't do anything, but if you know of a way to make it work I'd love to find out.

Answer (score -1):

Although I do not know where you can find the QuartzFiles, here is an application that will allow you to set them to your backgrounds if and when you find them:

http://wallsaver.en.softonic.com/mac